Encrypted TLS 1.2 connection don't created between the .net framework 4.7.2 client and ActiveMQ Artemis
During the project's working proccess I get null in the line: connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoints); without any exception. ActiveMQ Artemis also does not record any errors during the connection attempts.
I need to create connection with ActiveMQ Artemis running on the Docker container. The connection must by encrypted via TLS 1.2. All needed certificates must be located only in ActiveMQ Artemis.
.Net client shouldn't get any certificates, because project is written on Framework 4.7.2 and will be run using Mono on Linux, and Mono has no support of X509 certificates.
Attempt of sending messages to the same ActiveMQ Artemis by simple TCP using this .NET library works correctly.
For creating the connection I use ".NET Client for Apache ActiveMQ Artemis" library.
Here's the code that creates ConnectionFactory, etc:
public class AmqMessageBrokerService : IAmqMessageBrokerService
{
    private readonly IBrokerConfigSection brokerConfigSection;
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private List<Endpoint> endpoints = new List<Endpoint>();
    private ProducerConfiguration producerConfiguration;
    private IConnection connection;
    private IProducer producer;
    private bool isConnected = false;

    public AmqMessageBrokerService(
        IBrokerConfigSection brokerConfigSection)
    {
        this.brokerConfigSection = brokerConfigSection;

        connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory()
        {
            SSL =
            {
                ClientCertificates = null,
                Protocols = SslProtocols.Tls12,
                CheckCertificateRevocation = false,
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = null,
                LocalCertificateSelectionCallback = null
            }
        };

        var endpoint = Endpoint.Create(
            host: "localhost",
            port: 61617,
            user: brokerConfigSection.ArtemisMQUserName,
            password: brokerConfigSection.ArtemisMQPassword,
            scheme: Scheme.Amqps,
            path: brokerConfigSection.ArtemisMQConnectionString);

        endpoints.Add(endpoint);

        producerConfiguration = new ProducerConfiguration()
        {
            Address = "MyAdress"
        };
    }

    public async Task StartSendMessagesToAmqAsync(
        ISyslogReadQueueManageService syslogReadQueueManageService,
        CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            Console.WriteLine("Connecting with ArtemisMq is started...\n");

            var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(10000);
            var acceptTask = CreateAmqConnectionAsync();

            await Task.WhenAny(timeoutTask, acceptTask);

            if (!acceptTask.IsCompleted)
            {
                continue;
            }

            await SendMessageToArtemisAsync(
                syslogReadQueueManageService,
                ct);

        }
    }

    private async Task CreateAmqConnectionAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            connection = await connectionFactory.CreateAsync(endpoints);

            producer = await connection.CreateProducerAsync(producerConfiguration);

            isConnected = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Connection with ArtemisMq created suxesfull.\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Exception during the connecting to ArtemisMq: {ex.Message}\n");
            isConnected = false;
        }
    }
}

Here's the BrokerConfigSection from the App.config file of my project:
<BrokerConfigSection 
    ArtemisMQConnectionString="tcp://0.0.0.0:61617" 
    ArtemisMQUserName="admin" 
    ArtemisMQPassword="admin" 
    ArtemisMQQueueName="ExpiryQueue">
</BrokerConfigSection>

Here is the acceptor's configuration in broker.xml file of ActiveMQ Artemis:
<acceptor name="amqps-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61617?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;sslEnabled=true;keyStoreAlias=amq1;keyStorePath=file:/certs/keystore.jks;keyStorePassword=11111111;enabledProtocols=TLSv1.2</acceptor>


What kind of certificates are you using? Are they self-signed or signed by a trusted authority? Have you enabled SSL debug logging on the JVM running ActiveMQ Artemis? If so, what did it show when the .NET client attempted to connect?

Is your Docker configuration correct to expose port 61617 to external access?

@JustinBertram , tried to use .jks, .p12 and .pem self-signed certificates. Port 61617 is available for external connection. Don't use SSL debug on the JVM in container. How can I set it up?

Are you certificates self-signed or signed by a trusted authority?

@JustinBertram , self-signed, created using terminal commands. Using this certificates while was configuring the TLS 1.2 connection with Syslog server - all worked correctly. May be have problems with creation logic of ConnectionFactory & Endpoint.

If you're using self-signed certificates then the client will need to have that certificate in its trust store. Are you specifying this on the client?

For general information on enabling SSL debug logging for Java see this. As far as ActiveMQ Artemis is concerned you can put Java system properties in etc/artemis.profile.

@JustinBertram , if we talk about it: "during using self-signed certificates then the client will need to have that certificate in its trust store.".
I can't use any certificates in the client side, because the system, that will be running my program on Linux doesn't have the necessary libraries to support any kinds of certificates. Is there any way to not use certificates on the client?
